# nhibernate oracleBulkCopy c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

De acordo com a imagem em anexo, eu tenho uma classe atributo acompanhado do método `ListarMunicipio`, onde possui uma lista, no método em seguida eu tenho `public static void InserirOuAtualizar(Municipio municipio)`, estou trabalhando com a funcionalidade `nhubernet`, dentro desse método eu gostaria de atribuir o `OracleBulkInsert`, para inserir as informações em massa, em um outro código que fiz de teste usando o `SqlBulkInsert` e o banco de dados `Sql Server` eu consegui, porém como aqui na empresa trabalhamos com camadas, gostaria de saber se é possível eu aplicar a função `OracleBulkInsert` nesse método `InserirouAtualizar`?

Eu possuo esse código da função `BulkCopy` abaixo usado para o `SQL`, queria saber como eu posso aplicar ele no método de inserir da imagem sem ter a necessidade de passar a string de conexão até porque já existe a classe para isso.

Segue o código que quero aplicar dentro do método `InserirouAtualizar` da imagem.

```
private void SqlBulkCopyImport(DataTable dtExcel)
{

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection()

        //@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="" + caminho + "";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1';"
        {
            // Abrir conexão.
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                // Especificando o nome do destino da tabela.
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "sdpj_import_processo";

                foreach (DataColumn dc in dtExcel.Columns)
                {
                    // Como o numeros das colunas do excel 
                    // não é igual ao numeros de colunas da tabela, precisamos mapear as colunas.

                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.ColumnName);
                }

                // Escreva o destino do arquivo.
                //Define o nome da tabela

                //[OPTIONAL]: Mapeie as colunas do Excel com a da tabela do banco de dados 
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Data de Requisição Pgto", "DAT_REQ_PGTO");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NUMERO PROCESSO ANTERIOR", "NUM_PROC_ANTERIOR");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NUMERO JUDICIAL", "NUM_PROC_JUDICIAL");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("COMARCA", "DSC_COMARCA");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("VARA", "NUM_VARA");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("VARANOME", "NME_VARA");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NOME", "NME_INTERESSADO");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CPF", "CPF_CNPJ_INTERESSADO");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DEENDERECO", "DSC_ENDERECO");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NUENDERECO", "NUM_ENDERECO");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NMMUNICIPIO", "NME_MUNICIPIO");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DECOMPLEMENTO", "DSC_DECOMPLEMENTO");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DEBAIRRO", "NME_BAIRRO");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NUCEP", "NUM_CEP");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("NMMUNICIPIO", "NME_MUNICIPIO");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("BRUTO", "VLR_BRUTO");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("IRPF", "VLR_IR");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("LIQUIDO", "VLR_LIQUIDO");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Nº SEP", "COD_SEP");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DATA SEP", "DAT_SEP");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DATA DE RECEBIMENTO NA ORIGEM", "DAT_RECEB_ORIGEM");

                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcel);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]